# A better way of presenting a UITableView subview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I currently have a `UITableView` containing a list of playlists, naturally if the user wants to see what each playlist contains they need to press the playlist row and a new table will present itself containing the tables details same as the standard iOS music app. However at the moment I do this by calling an entirely new `UIViewController` with an entirely different table in it, this strikes me as very inefficient for Apple, so I am wondering if there is a better way to implement this.

I can't seem to find anything in the way of articles or tutorials on presenting subviews of this sort (I have a feeling I'm using the wrong keywords) What do you do in this circumstance?

Comment: This is the normal iOS flow, but you are free to do something else, maybe expand the table in place by inserting extra cells for the details.

Comment: Thanks, however after looking at what I need to display it would unfortunatly seem best in most cases to have a seperate viewcontroller, that idea might work well in the case of Artists/Albums/songs tab for albums though